# Tab Bar controller with code or with template?

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller

I want to create an iOS app which will have use a Tab Bar controller. I know you can set this up by a template within XCode or you can just code it straight, but I'm unclear why use one approach over the other? other than I presume the template allows you to use the interface builder? if I don't want to use interface builder (and I don't) is there any point to using the tab bar app template? can I use the template but remove the interface builder bits? or if I'm doing that I might as well not use the template and just code the controller directly?

Answer (score 1):

As board as the question sounds, let us look at it as a design decision and personal preference.

The Interface Builder allows you to design your layout quickly while providing you the visual bits - you know, how it would look like while designing it.

Can you achieve the same result programmatically? Yes, sure, if you can see it (where the UI element is, the color, the position it has in relation to the other elements, etc etc) while designing in your mind.

Let's say you wanted to have a `UIButton`, just a button, plain and have it hooked to a method called `clicked` when pressed. In IB you could achieve that within seconds.

Comparing that to doing it programmatically:

```
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(clicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[button setTitle:@"play a beep" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
button.frame = CGRectMake(80.0f, 80.0f, 40.0f, 40.0f);
[self.view addSubview:button];
```

You could do it either way - in IB or in code.

For the above case, would doing it in IB faster? Yes. But it doesn't prevent you from also doing it programmatically - it's your preference.

This serves to provide a general answer; because there are many cases involved while designing the interface as to whether one should use IB or do it programmatically.

Can you remove the IB bits? Yes.

Analogy:

Take it as buying a car and pimp it up with fog lamps, have it re-painted etc.

But if you decide to pimp your own ride by replacing every single bits on the car you buy, then why buy a car to do that and not just build one from scratch?